# QueryDSL SQL bean generation without connection information

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jdbc, querydsl

I want to use QueryDSL to do SQL queries in a Spring Boot 2 microservice. This service will execute in different environments and each one of them will have different database connections that will be loaded from the application-.yml files.
Looking at the QueryDSL documentation, it seems that, if I want to generate Q* files for SQL, I have to put the connection details in the pom directly:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <jdbcDriver>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</jdbcDriver>
          <jdbcUrl>jdbc:derby:target/demoDB;create=true</jdbcUrl>
          <packageName>com.myproject.domain</packageName>
          <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>${derby.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But I can't do it because the connection details will vary depending on the profile that's used to run the service and it can't be known at compile time.

Is there a way to create just the Q* files from the domain beans without providing the connection details?